# How to return inflated view by web call response data

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-volley, layout-inflater

The onCreateView method terminates without waiting for the response from the web service. Naturally, view is returning null. Everything else works right. What I mean is given below.

```
private View view;
private View notExistedOwnStory;
private View existedOwnStory;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

...

notExistedOwnStory = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_writestory, container, false);
existedOwnStory = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_deletestory, container, false);

checkOwnStory(storyID, username);

if(view == notExistedOwnStory){

       ...

    }

    if (view == existedOwnStory) {

        ...

    }

    return view;
}

private void checkOwnStory(final String storyID,final String username) {

    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_checkOwnStory";

    pDialog.setMessage("Checking Own Story ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, AppConfig.CHECK_OWN_STORY, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Checking Own Story Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {

                    // here is the set according to the response
                    view = existedOwnStory;

                } else {

                    view = notExistedOwnStory;
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Checking Own Story Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting params to check own story url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("storyID", storyID);
            params.put("username", username);

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

What to do if the checkOwnStory method is completely ended and the onCreateView method works accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct design. 
onCreateView() runs on main thread so you can not simply wait in this method to inflate views. Hence you can inflate an XML (Probably with Progress dialog) to show interim progress.

You can post a message through Handler from the `public void onResponse(String response)` using `Handler.post()` method after you parse JSON successfully.

You can implement `handleMessage()` method and based on the message you get from `onResponse()` method you can add whichever view you want either programmatically(`addView`) or from XML file through a ViewStub may be and update that View to `View.VISIBLE`.

Comment: I have done with your design, i just was wondering that whether the design which i asked is more better or not. Thanks for answering.

Comment: It's is not a better design if life cycle methods like onCreateView(), onStart() and so on does long time consuming work. Since we are expected to design a responsive UI